# Error in appcompat_v7 resources when new sdk installed

Tags: android, sdk

I have updated my all sdk and api version , .... to the last version. but now i have an error in my appcompat_v7. I also reimported the appcompat_v7 project from android sdk support library folder. But it didn't work. my min sdk version is api7 in the project and target sdk is api22 (android 5.1.1). I get this error:`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.`

[image: ScreenShot]

How can i solve it?

Thank you for your advice.

(sorry for my bad English!)

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: I added a screen shot. I closed all the other projects except appcompat_v7.

Comment: Check if the appcompat_v7 project's compile sdk version greater than or equal to 21. To do that, `Right click on appcompat_v7-> Properties -> Android`. Select API level 22. Also update it's manifest.

Comment: I checked it. it's on API level 22 (Android 5.1.1). Also my eclipse version is Luna  4.4. can it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I also tryed it on other Eclipse versions. but it didn't solve.

Comment: Could you post the contents of project.properties from android-support-v7-appcompat directory in your workspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79626/discussion-between-shubhadeep-chaudhuri-and-saeed-ketabi).